# Referencing a selector causes an InflationException

Tags: android, themes, selector, android-drawable

I'm trying to develop two themes for my app, and depending on the theme, I need a View to use a different selector. Though when I create a reference which determines the correct selector to use, I get an InflationException error.

Here's my attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="ReditrTheme">
        <attr name="downvoteArrow" format="reference" />
        <attr name="upvoteArrow" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="VoteState">
        <attr name="enabled" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Here's my themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="upvoteArrow">@drawable/upvote_states</item>
        <item name="downvoteArrow">@drawable/downvote_states</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LightTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="upvoteArrow">@drawable/upvote_states_l</item>
        <item name="downvoteArrow">@drawable/downvote_states_l</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Here's my upvote_states.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.reditr.app">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_top_colored" app:enabled="true"/>
<item style="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_top" app:enabled="false"/>

</selector>
```

Here's my upvotes_states_l.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.reditr.app">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_top_colored" app:enabled="true"/>
<item style="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_top_l" app:enabled="false"/>

</selector>
```

downvotes_states.xml and downvotes_states_l.xml are identical to the ones above, they just use ic_action_arrow_bottom instead.

Finally, here's my View that I'm trying to apply the reference to:

```
<com.example.views.UpvoteView
    android:id="@+id/upvote"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="?attr/upvoteArrow" />
```

I tried a few solutions online but they were always a bit slightly different to my issue and didn't fix my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized the mistake I made. In my states.xml files, I used the style attribute for some reason, it should have been android:drawable.